Can I run pymodbus simulator as a worker in digitalocean?
I use DigitalOcean's App Platform for many static sites and web services. Now I would like to run a pymodbus simulator  using that App Platform. I'm not sure what I shouls start with?
I think a worker might work. I wonder if anyone had tried that?
